# ipad and iphone microphone different behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am trying out an application on pitch detection based on [Demetri Miller Tutorial](http://demetrimiller.com/2011/01/25/pitch-detection-in-ios-4-x/). But i am having issues when i try it with iPad. Is it because the microphone settings of iPhone and iPad are different.

The app works for iPhone and in simulator,but when it comes to ipad not always working.I have tested with 2-3 iPads and all are having this problem. So confirmed not problem with mic of iPad.Is there a way i can increase the microphone performance of iPad. Since the way mic is behaving in case of iPhone and iPad is different.

Is there any specific setting changes on ipad that needs to be done?

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: At some points the app in ipad stops detecting where as in iphone there is no issues.Just wanted to know if some microphone specific setting has to be made..